# How to disable Device Performance & Health "Some apps stopped working"?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to disable this type of alert so that in the future Windows doesn't report it to me as something that I should be fixing? Dismissing it every time it pops up is becoming annoying (which is probably the intent).

[image]